# background-image eval

Tags: asp.net, background-image, eval

I am using `DataList` to show thumbnails, how can I use background-image url with `eval`

This code gives me  The server tag is not well formed error.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListPortfolio" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
        <ItemTemplate>

<asp:Image ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
           style="background-image: url('<%#Eval("featuredImagesSmall")%>');" />

        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, you probably just want to use a `div` instead of `<asp:Image` (which renders as an `img`), in order to achieve thumbnails that are all the same size regardless of the image size:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListPortfolio" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style='width:100px;height:100px;background-position:center;background-image:url(<%# Eval("featuredImagesSmall") %>)'></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I just put an arbitrary height and width on the div, but that will ensure all the thumbnails are the same size. You can play with the CSS to position the image inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the ImageUrl property of the ASP.NET Image control? Something like this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListPortfolio" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
        <ItemTemplate>

<asp:Image ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("featuredImagesSmall")%>' />

        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: ... that would be `ImageUrl='<%# Eval("featuredImagesSmall")%>'` or something similar. The way you have the quotes will cause the same error.

Comment: i am using imageurl but images are not the same height and width.For the taller images i am trying to show just the center of the image so i heard that use background-image and some css for this.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev You are correct about the quotes. I missed that when I wrote the answer. Thanks for catching that.