# background-image not being displayed in div inside DataList ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I'm trying to set the `background-image` of a `div` within `ItemTemplate` of a `DataList` to the filename in `column` image_path in the `datatable` that's used as the listview's datasource.

Here's the code I'm currently using, which includes two `datalists`. It's based on the code found here:  [background-image eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011347/background-image-eval)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestWebApp.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DataList ID="DataListDiv" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="My lagel"></asp:Label>
                <div style='width:195px;height:162px;background-position:center;background-image:url(<%# Eval("image_path","~/Styles/Images/{0}") %>)'></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>

    <asp:DataList ID="DataListImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image_path","~/Styles/Images/{0}")%>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>



    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that `DataListDiv` is not being displayed. The 2nd `datalist` (`DataListImages`) is displayed, but it's using an `ImageButton`. Both are using the same `eval` so I know the binding is correct.

This is what the `datatable` looks like:

```
BedNum     Waiter     image_path
201        Joe        Red.png
202        Jim        Green.png
203        Mary       Red.png
204        Carl       Yellow.png
```

Comment: When I test your code, the image is always displayed. If you add Labels or TextBoxes in the `ItemTemplate`of `DataListDiv`, to show the value of the other fields, do you see them?

Comment: Yes, I see the label but I don't see the image. Do you see both datalists with images?

Comment: I posted all the html. Maybe there's something wrong somewhere else?

Comment: I just tested the first one (`DataListDiv`). Do you see something special in the HTML output (with "View Page Source" in the browser)?

Comment: Apparently, the relative path is not interpreted the same way in the `div's` `background-image` as in the `ImageUrl`. In the `div`, I changed the `eval` from `Eval("image_path","~/Styles/Images/{0}")` to `Eval("image_path","Styles/Images/{0}")` and it worked,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the relative path in `background-image:url` for the `div` by eliminating the **~/** :

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListDiv" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style='width:195px;height:162px;background-position:center;background-image:url(<%# Eval("image_path","Styles/Images/{0}") %>)'></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```